# pytest - importing class missing attribute

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to python and I am trying to write a simple test to test a class.

My folder structure is like:

```
lib
  mycode
     __init__.py
     my_calc.py
  tests
     __init__.py
     test_my_calc.py
```

I am running pytest inside the lib folder.

Here is my python class:

```
class MyCalc:

    def add(a,b):
        return a + b
```

And my test_my_calc.py looks like:

```
from mycode import my_calc

def test_add():
    assert my_calc.add(2,2) == 4
```

I am receiving this error when I run pytest:

```
E       AttributeError: module 'mycode.my_calc' has no attribute 'add'
```

So then I tried to import the `Class` bit got a different error:

```
from mycode import MyCalc

def test_add():
    assert MyCalc.add(2,2) == 4
```

I get this error:

```
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'MyCalc' from 'mycode'
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: I don't see you importing a class anywhere. You imported the `my_calc` module.

Comment: I tried that and got a different error, let me update my Q

Comment: `MyCalc` is part of `my_calc`, not `mycode`.

Comment: this was the issue, my import was incorrect, it seems I need to import like `from mycode.my_calc import MyCalc`  this worked.  If you post as an answer I'll accept